# Dashboard tool for a custom SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, html, open-source, dashboard

For a project I'm working on I have build a reporting database in SQL Server. We are pretty much free to design the structure of the DB and what we put it in.

However, now comes the fun part and we would need to be able to visualize the data in some nice dashboards.

Can anybody provide me with some suggestions on an easy to use tool (end-users will need to be able to manipulate the dashboards) that is not dependent on the underlying database technology? (if its based on SQL Server I can live with that :))

I've looked in to Kibana but seems to be only possible if you use ElasticSearch.
Currently investigating Grafana to see what that brings me so anything in that realm would be appreciated!

Comment: Stickly speaking *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*.  That said... Power BI looks good and is easy to use.  Qlikview and Tableau are also big sellers in this market.  When designing the backend bear in mind; most BI products are designed to run on top of a [dimensionally modeled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling) [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did not see the off-topic part but guess I'll refrain from this type of question in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could check out [PowerBI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) or [Syncfusion Dashboard Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard). Both are easy to use and have very nice graphs. In the latter, you can even write your own SQL if a database is your data source.

Comment: Eventually decided to go with Power BI. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

[Syncfusion Dashboard Designer](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-designer/overview), a good tool to design a dashboard by connect your SQL database and it can be easily shared to your users using Syncfusion Dashboard Server or the dashboard can be embedded into your application (WPF/Windows Forms/ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC/HTML5/LightSwitch HTML etc.) through their Development Kit. Refer more detail, https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard.